# Recursive CTE to find present and previous WorkState and entry time of the WorkState

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the below

[image]

The schema is as under

```
declare @t table(CustomerId varchar(10),WorkState varchar(10),statechangedate datetimeoffset, stateorder int)
insert into @t 
    select '1','WorkStateA','2018-10-30 13:38:53.5133333 +00:00',1 union all
    select '2','WorkStateA','2018-05-18 17:04:56.9900000 +00:00',1 union all
    select '2','WorkStateA','2018-05-18 16:22:20.3266667 +00:00',2 union all
    select '2','WorkStateB','2018-05-09 12:46:33.8300000 +00:00',3 union all
    select '3','WorkStateF','2018-06-21 12:40:03.2933333 +00:00',1 union all
    select '3','WorkStateE','2018-06-21 12:38:43.9000000 +00:00',2 union all
    select '3','WorkStateD','2018-06-21 12:38:24.7533333 +00:00',3 union all
    select '3','WorkStateC','2018-06-21 12:38:11.0233333 +00:00',4 union all
    select '3','WorkStateB','2018-06-21 12:38:04.1933333 +00:00',5 union all
    select '3','WorkStateA','2018-06-21 12:36:51.4633333 +00:00',6 
select * from @t
```

What I am looking for

[image]

Means I need to capture the Present and Previous WorkState and Entry time of the WorkState on customer basis.

I have tried with the below recursive CTE

```
;with cte as(
select 
    t.CustomerId, 
    PresentWorkState = t.WorkState,
    PresentStatechangedate = t.statechangedate, 
    t.stateorder, 
    PreviousWorkState = null ,
    PreviousStatechangedate=  null 
from @t t where t.stateorder=1
union all
select 
    t1.CustomerId, 
    t1.WorkState,
    t1.statechangedate, 
    c.stateorder,
    c.PreviousWorkState,
    c.PreviousStatechangedate
from  @t t1
join cte c on t1.stateorder !=c.stateorder)

select *
from cte
```

but could not.

Comment: Which dbms you using? sql-server?

Comment: yes, SQL server 2016

Comment: When you say *prevoius*, I guess you refer to the *one* WorkState right before and not *all* that were before through earlier states - if so, it is not recursion.

Comment: It looks like you don't need recusive CTE for that, but [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (or [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)) window function.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Lead function did it. Thanks
@Andrey, though I have accepted Zeki Gumus answer,  but many thanks to you for the pointer.

Comment: Tips for better questions here: (1) we prefer questions without thanks-in-advance and please-halp pleading - keep it succinct and stick to technical writing; (2) if you "could not" do something, explain why this is; (c) post answers in the answer space, rather than merging them into the question. At 11K of reputation, readers would generally expect you to know these things already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Andrew said `LAG()` should work for your purpose instead of using recursive cte. Check this:

```
SELECT *
        ,LAG(WorkState) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY statechangedate)
        ,LAG(statechangedate) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY statechangedate)
FROM @T
ORDER BY CustomerId,statechangedate
```

Comment: No, it's Lead function. I just tried. I mean Lag is also correct , it 's the other way around

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar Are you sure LEAD(). with your expected result it seems you need to use LAG().

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

LEAD function solved it. Here is the output:

```
select 
    CustomerId,
    PresentWorkState = WorkState,
    PresentStatechangedate = statechangedate,
    PreviousWorkState = LEAD(WorkState) OVER (partition by CustomerId ORDER BY stateorder) ,
    PreviousStatechangedate = LAG(statechangedate) OVER (partition by CustomerId ORDER BY stateorder)
from @t
```

[image]